# How to know if I can delete with my oracle user? Without actually deleting anything?

Tags: oracle

That's it:

How to know if I can delete with my oracle user? Without actually deleting anything?

I'm using a database that I don't own, nor have full access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is available in the data-dictionary.

You can check for direct grants to you via:

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'DELETE';
```

You can also check for privileges accessible through a `ROLE` by:

```
SELECT ROLE, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM SESSION_ROLES
INNER JOIN ALL_TAB_PRIVS
ON SESSION_ROLES.ROLE = ALL_TAB_PRIVS.GRANTEE
AND PRIVILEGE = 'DELETE';
```

Comment: also know that your user can delete any row in a table in your schema or drop any table that is in your schema - because your user OWNS those objects